# Team Foundation Server 2010: How to report Code Reviewers

Tags: tfs

I work with a company that makes use of Team Foundation Server 2010 (TFS) for source control. We have a policy in place that requires those checking files into source control to enter the name of a code reviewer. This has been working well, as we have good support for this policy from management. However, we have discovered that some people are simply entering "N/A" into the code reviewer spot, instead of someone's name. We would like some way to report on this, or otherwise determine who, when, and where "N/A" is being entered.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) installed you can run the command `tfpt searchcs` from the command line. This will bring up a UI that allows you to search for changesets using a number of criteria, the code reviewer should be one of the fields you can search on.

Comment: I confirm, you can search a changeset based on the check-in notes content.